# Webkit improper rendering of toggled input field

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, positioning

I have a search field that shows/hides when the user rolls over a search icon.  On webkit, the input field is positioned incorrectly after the search field is first shown, clicked on, and hidden again.  On Firefox it seems to work properly.

Play around with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Efams/

Try combinations of hovering on/off the search icon and clicking in the input field and you'll see the positioning error on webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fixed it or if I just haven't been able to replicate it since the change, but adding `stop(true,true)` prior to your animation effects may be the cure.

http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/Efams/1/

**EDIT:**

Nevermind, just got it to replicate.